# Matlab production server add methods dynamically to deployable archive

Tags: matlab

i am developing a web site where users can test Matlab methods and their own.
i am using Restful api of Matlab, and i am linking it to nodejs .
I want to know if there is a way to add a Matlab files to the deployable archive
while the matlab server is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

The workflow is that you get your code, you use MATLAB Compiler SDK to compile the code to a `.ctf` file, and you deploy the `.ctf` file to MATLAB Production Server. Once the code is compiled to a `.ctf` file it is fixed, and can't be modified.

If you need to modify it, you need to modify the code, recompile to a new `.ctf` file, and redeploy the new file.